# Sencha Touch - When switching Items using setActiveItem(), how can I access the Back button?

Tags: sencha-touch

**Problem:**

I switch Panels using *setActiveItem()* according to question-answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291460/sencha-touch-tabbar-page-navigation-why-its-breaking/8313591#8313591)

```
App.views.viewport.getActiveItem().setActiveItem(App.views.Panel, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' });
```

Everything works fine, but how can I access my back button?

I suspect that theres only 1 back button, and I have to change his properties (text, handler).
How Can I do that?

Thank you, Shlomi.

P.S- when thinking about it, I have to modify all the bar properties - its title as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this question referencing the [previous question about panels.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291460/sencha-touch-tabbar-page-navigation-why-its-breaking/8313591#8313591)

First add a back button to your panel's top bar.

```
initComponent: function () {
      Ext.apply(this, {
       dockedItems: [{
            xtype: "toolbar",
            title: "Ingressos",
            items:[{
                 xtype: 'button',
                 text: 'Back',
                 handler: function () {

                 }
            }]
       }],
       items: [Mobz.views.IngressosList]
    });
   Mobz.views.Ingressos.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

After that when user goes to next page, access the back button and change it's handler(I won't prefer to change handler, I prefer build a stack mechanism to go bacward but it is your choice :) ).

```
Mobz.views.viewport.getActiveItem() //panel

Mobz.views.viewport.getActiveItem().dockedItems.items[0] // toolbar
```

You are seeking back button;

```
Mobz.views.viewport.getActiveItem().dockedItems.items[0].items.items[0] // back button

Mobz.views.viewport.getActiveItem().dockedItems.items[0].title // toolbars title
```

Comment: Thanks @ykartal, as usual! I will dig on the stack order. I discovered it only after I published the question. Thank you.

Comment: by saying stack mechanism, do you mean the prev() method?

Comment: I think yes. If you hold previous panels in an array and when back button clicked take last of the array and remove it from array and when go forward open the new window and add it to the array.

Comment: But isn't prev() is enough? Isn't prev() holds the stack order?

Comment: Thank you very much, my Turkish friend :)))) The array did the job. Took me time to reach it. I investigated different approaches, but that one seemed to be the most efficient, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Back',
    handler: function () {
        App.views.viewport.setActiveItem([The panel you want to go], {type: 'slide', direction: 'right'});
    }
}
```

Add a button in your "App.views.viewport" panel.